# Running OpenMP on a single node of a cluster

Tags: c, batch-file, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, openmp

I am able to do simple for loops in OpenMP on my desktop/laptop of the form (a mild simplification of what I actually have...)

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <omp.h>
 %%%% #include other libraries...

 int main(void){
 .
 .
 .
 %%% declare and initialize variables.
 .
 .
 .

 #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) shared(tf, p, Fx, Fy, Fz) private(v, i,j,k,t0) 
 for (i = 0; i < Nx; i++){
 for (j = 0; j < Ny; j++){
 for (k = 0; k < Nz; k++){

 v[0] = Fx[i][j][k]; 
 v[1] = Fy[i][j][k];
 v[2] = Fz[i][j][k];
 ///My_fn changes v and then I put it back into Fx, Fy, Fz
 My_fn(v, t0, tf, p);   
 Fx[i][j][k] = v[0]; 
 Fy[i][j][k] = v[1];
 Fz[i][j][k] = v[2];
 }
 }
 }
 }
```

If I want, I can even specify to use n_threasds = 1, 2, 3  or 4 cores on my laptop by adding `omp_set_num_threads(n_threads);` to the top, and I notice the performance I want.  However, when using a cluster, I comment that line out.

I have access to a cluster and would like to run the code **on a single node** since the cluster has nodes with up to 48 cores and my laptop only 4.  When I use the cluster, after compiling, I type into the terminal

```
 $export OMP_NUM_THREADS=10
 $bsub -n 10 ./a.out
```

But the program does not run properly: I output into a file and see it took 0 seconds to run, and the the values of Fx, Fy and Fz are what they are when I initiate them, so it seems the loop is not even run at all.

*Edit*: This issue was addressed by the people who managed the cluster, and is likely very specific to that cluster, hence I caution people to relate the issue to their specific case.

Comment: When you write *cluster* I think *distributed-memory*.  What steps are you taking to ensure that your OpenMP job runs on only one node of your cluster ?

Comment: Yes, OpenMP can only be run on a single computer, but on a cluster that I have access to, there are many nodes with 20 - 46 processors that are better than my 4 core laptop...

Comment: Then you sent us in a completely wrong direction with the information that you gave us. Your problem thus has nothing to do with a cluster.  I propose that to close the question (title and everything is completely misleading) and that you reformulate it properly and come back with a new one.

Comment: I can get the program running on my laptop without any issues.  What else could be the issue?  The cluster has OpenMP, gcc, etc. on it, so that doesn't seem to be the issue:  Thus, I suspect though I could be wrong, that the issue is that I am trying to run a parallelized for loop using OpenMP on a single node on a cluster and I'm not familiar with doing so.  So I still stand by suspicion that the issue is linked with me working on a cluster.

Comment: I clarified that I only want to use a single node on a cluster.]

Comment: Please indent your code

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me that this question has nothing to do with programming but rather with using the batch system (a.k.a. distributed resource manager) on your cluster. The usual practice is to write a script instead and inside the script set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to the number of slots granted. Your batch system appears to be LSF (a wild guess, based on the presence of `bsub`), then you'd mostly like to have something similar in the script (let's call it `job.sh`):

```
#BSUB -n 10

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$LSB_DJOB_NUMPROC
./a.out
```

Then submit the script with `bsub < job.sh`. LSF exports the number of slots granted to the job in the `LSB_DJOB_NUMPROC` environment variable. By doing the assignment you may submit the same job file with different parameters like: `bsub -n 20 < job.sh`. You might need to give a hint to the scheduler that you'd like to have all slots on the same node. One can usually do that by specifying `-R "span[ptile=n]"`. There might be other means to do that, e.g. an `esub` executable that you might need to specify:

```
#BSUB -a openmp
```

Please, note that Stack Overflow is not where your administrators store the cluster documentation. You'd better ask them, not us.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand correctly what you are up to, but I fear that your idea is that OpenMP would automatically run your application in a distributed way on a cluster.

OpenMP is not made for such a task, it supposes that you run your code in a shared memory setting. For a distributed setting (processors only connected through a networking link) there are other tools, namely MPI. But such a setting is a bit more complicated to set up than just the `#pragma` annotations that you are used to when using openMP.

Comment: Yes, OpenMP can only be run on a single computer, but on a cluster that I have access to, there are many nodes with 20 - 46 processors that are better than my 4 core laptop...

Answer (score 1):

Hristo is right, but i think you should add

```
#BSUB -R "span[hosts=1]"            # run on a single node
```

in your .sh file. The ptile option is only to specify the number of tasks per node
, see i.e

https://doc.zih.tu-dresden.de/hpc-wiki/bin/view/Compendium/PlatformLSF

Otherwise, depending on the queue settings of the cluster, which you might get with

```
bqueues -l
```

the task would be runned on every node, which is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the node has 24 cores

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=24
```

in my system. Probably in the cluster you use it will be like

```
#BSUB -l nodes=1:ppn=24
```